# USB Barcode scanner splitter

Tags: usb, splitters, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a device similar to this one:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efs6DaTFLto

I need to scan a barcode and send the text to two computers via USB.

Pics from video:

[image]
[image]

The device in the video is not for sale and I can't find anything similar elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any reason a software solution couldn't solve your problem here? You could scan to a single machine and put the barcode in a database. Any number of other machines could then access it.

Comment: I could do it in one computer, but not the other one, it uses 3rd party software and I don't have control over it. I'm thinking however on a timer reading the latest value from the database and somehow "emulating" keyboard strokes in each computer

Comment: Does the connection to the two PCs really have to be by USB?

Comment: Not necessarily, it could be use the serial port with a serial -> keyboard emulator, but it would be much simpler with USB

Comment: Why not wifi or bluetooth? I ask because I know of a solution that uses this connection type.

Comment: Sure, I'll consider anything, Please post an answer :)